# Breakpoint on entry point of PE is failed

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm trying to get log of activity of my application with WinDbg. At the moment I'm on Win10 Pro x64. The entry point of my application is 0x10004D7EC. After start of WinDbg I press Ctrl+E to select my app. I input the next command

```
    bp 10004D7EC
```

then hit F5 but WinDbg says that ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY has been occured (0x12B) so it seems that loading `logexts` is a bad idea because there is no garanty that information will be correct. So, how to fix this or maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: instead of all the script clipboard and copy paste you can use the pseudo register @$exentry  type g @$exentry and hit enter  or type bp @$exentry and hit f5

Comment: Yeah, I read about $exentry but it doesn't work for me that's why I use script below. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're getting the error  because you are putting your breakpoint on an invalid memory location. Check in the memory/disassembly window in `windbg` what is at this memory location - you'll probably find nothing there.

I guess that `10004D7EC` is the address of your entry point on the disk - which might be different from the entry point address at runtime. You can search for the entry point with: `x <your module name>!*<your entry point name>*` (i.e. `x myApp!*main*`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! At the moment I can not vote but I give you +10 telepathically. You are right about entry point but I solved the problem with next way: start WinDbg, press Ctrl+E, select myapp. Then type `.shell -ci "!dh myapp -f" for /f "token=1" %i in ('findstr /irc:"entry"') do @echo %i | clip` This one copies address of entry point to the clipboard. Now I can set the breakpoint `bp myapp+` + Ctrl+V and hit Enter. This works well. Of course, it doesn't work on packed PE or PE which entry point has been manually edited.